# C# String.Equals returns false on identical strings

Tags: c#, string, compare, equals-operator

I am working on a project and for a part of it I need to compare 2 strings.
My issue comes that whenever I try to compare them I always get false `(==, .Equals(), String.Equals()` - they all return false, even though I have 2 completely identical strings)

Here is a part of my code.

```
var tagType = JObject.Parse(json).First.First.ToString();
foreach (var type in assembly.ExportedTypes)
{
    var name = tagType;
    var currentType = type.Name;

    var a = name.Length;
    var b = currentType.Length;

    var result = currentType == name;
    var result1 = currentType.Equals(name);
    var result2 = String.Equals(name, currentType, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    var result3 = String.Equals(name, currentType, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    var result4 = String.Equals(name, currentType, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var result5 = String.Equals(name, currentType, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Now when debugging my `foreach`, I eventually reach a point where name and `currentType` both equal the same string - "AutoIncrementTag". At that same point their lengths (a and b) are equal - 16 characters.

This is what the debug output looks like:

```
//name -        "AutoIncrementТаg"
//currentType - "AutoIncrementTag"

//a - 16
//b - 16

// result - false
// result1 - false
// result2 - false
// result3 - false
// result4 - false
// result5 - false
```

And ALL of the comparisons below return false.

I even tried creating a new string out of both "name" and currenType. And nothing.

I am really stuck here. How can two identical strings (same length, so no hidden characters) return false with any kind of comparison.

Comment: If `String.Equals` returns false, the strings aren't identical. What is the value of result when debugging?

Comment: Can you provide a verifiable example? Just by plane code, it seems that your strings are not equal.

Comment: Just edited my post to show the debug output that troubles me. I hope it illustrates my problem. (The values are all copy/pasted from the debug window)

Comment: Are you sure that that are the EXACT strings? No tab/linebreak/null characters in one of the strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second last and third last characters are not the same.

One of the second last characters is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm and the other is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0430/index.htm . They **look** the same, but aren't actually the same.

To see it, run this program:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static string GetEscapeSequence(char c)
        {
            return "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X4");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var name = "AutoIncrementТаg";
            var currentType = "AutoIncrementTag";

            foreach (var character in name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(GetEscapeSequence(character));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("second string");
            foreach (var character in currentType)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(GetEscapeSequence(character));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Helped me out a lot. I ended up renaming my class name to the one that I had, and it works correctly now

Comment: These kinds of problems are real head scratchers!

Answer (score 1):

For the two strings, also compare the byte arrays.

```
string string1 = "AutoIncrementТаg";
string charArray = string.Join( ",", string1.ToCharArray().Select(s => (int)s));
```

For "AutoIncrementTag" you should get:

```
65,117,116,111,73,110,99,114,101,109,101,110,116,1058,1072,103
```

Comment: I actually must have cut and pasted the bad string.  The two high numbers ( 1058 and 1072) must be the bad characters.