# HashSet<string>.Contains not finding match with variable, but does with hard-coded string

Tags: c#, hashset

I've run into a weird situation when looking up a value in a `HashSet`.  It finds a match correctly when I pass in a hard-coded string, but not when using a variable whose contents are exactly the same as that hard-coded string.

This image and the debugging info at the bottom shows exactly the behavior I'm wondering about.  Why does `orgs.Contains(org)` return `false` while `orgs.Contains("Barr Family Practice")` returns `true`?  In this case, the contents of `org` are exactly "Barr Family Practice".

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio debugging]

Comment: Simple answer, the strings are not identical even though they look like they are. Do a `BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(org))` and compare when passing in the hardcoded string. My guess is that you either have one of the invisible joining characters in there, or one of the funky space characters.

Comment: Please share us a result of comparison `org == "Barr Family Practice"` in the "Locals" window.

Comment: Have to agree with @LasseV.Karlsen. I ran a test and cannot reproduce the error. Some thing you could try is to copy the string into notepad++, it has an option that will show you all the characters.

Comment: You can also check the output of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(org)` to see what is wrong.

Comment: You could also be using a custom equality-comparator inside the `HashSet<>` which only compares string-reference-equality instead of string-contents-equality (which may explain why string literals (which are generally interned to the same reference by the compiler) may be marked as equal by the HashSet.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes this was it!  One set of strings had spaces in it, while the others had non-breaking spaces.  Showing the constituent bytes as several commenters suggested revealed that in short order.  I added a String.Replace step to my ingestion logic and things work as expected now!  Is there a way we can add this as an anwer?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure there are many existing duplicates here on Stack Overflow already, I will see if I can find a suitable one.

Comment: I'm not super-happy about this possible duplicate so I won't vote to close it just yet, if anyone can find a good duplicate please do so, otherwise simply poach my comment above and post it as an answer (you can do that too rad-b if you want) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034482/c-sharp-string-equals-returns-false-on-identical-strings